# A subclass of regular graphs defined by a property of eigenvectors

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, adjacency-matrix

I am looking for the largest possible class of regular graphs such that it is possible to form a basis out of the eigenvectors of the graph's adjacency matrix with elements of each vector having the same absolute magnitude (they would differ only in complex phase).

A vector $v=(1,1, \ldots, 1)^{T}$ is an eigenvector of the adjacency matrix of a graph $G$ if and only if $G$ is [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph#Algebraic_properties). What about other eigenvectors? I know examples of regular graphs, e.g., finite <s>Cartesian integer lattices</s>  hypercubes on a integer lattice with  with periodic boundary conditions, such that there is a complete set of eigenvectors with  equal absolute values of the vector components (e.g., basis vectors for discrete Fourier transform). I am looking for a more general set of regulars graphs with such property.

Comment: It's clear you want undirected graphs, are you interested in simple undirected graphs only or do you want to consider multigraphs or graphs with self edges?

Comment: Undirected, with no self-edges. It is a physics-inspired question, with graph edges corresponding to allowed paths for particle hopping.

Comment: I don't really do physics so do you know what i mean by multigraphs? A multigraph allows multiple edges between each pair of vertices (nodes).

Comment: @N8tron I am interested in graphs with elements of the  adjacency matrix being either 0 or 1. That would exclude multigraphs, do I get you right?

Comment: Yes that clarifies it :)

Comment: Are finite cartesian integer latices grid graphs? Not many of these are regular if they're finite. Can you be a little more specific about an example or two?

Comment: @N8tron Perhaps I am misusing the terminology,  here is an example: a set of lattice vertices in the shape of a $d$-dimensional hypercube at coordinates $(n_1, n_2, \ldots n_d)$ where $n_k=0, 1, \ldots M-1$;  $k=1, \ldots, d$ and $d$ is the dimensionality. Periodic boundary conditions mean that the set of vertices is translationally invariant modulo $M$. Each vertex is connected to its $2d$ nearest neighbours, so the graph is regular.  The eigvenvectors are $\exp(i 2 \pi [m_1 n_1    + m_2 n_2 +  \ldots +m_d n_d]/M)$ where $m_k = 0, 1, \ldots d-1$, all elements have identical absolute values.

Comment: I would add the d dimensional hypercubes to your original post. Those are the only examples I know of so far. Maybe replace what you said about "finite Cartesian integer lattices" as I believe the hypercubes are the only ones in this family with the regularity property. I'm afraid things get rather large before they get interesting. The regularity condition puts a strict bounds on the corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$ to the (1,...,1) eigenvector. Specifically $\lambda$ is one less than the regularity degree $d$ which has $2 \le d \le n-1$ so $1\le \lambda \le n-2$.  Interesting but hard IMHO

Comment: Any Cayley graph for an abelian group will have this property.

Comment: @Chris Godsil this is exaclty the hint I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer but some partial results on constructing non-isomorphic graphs that share a basis of eigenvectors with coordinates in $\{-1,1\}$ including an eigenvector of all 1's.

Given a simple undirected graph $G$ of order $n$ the adjacency matrix $A$ will be a symmetric (that is $A^T=A$) $n \times n$ matrix. So the spectral theorem applies and A is orthogonally diagonizable. That is $A=PDP^T$ where $D$ is diagonal with real eigenvalues along the diagonal and the columns of $P$ form an orthonomal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. This means $P$ is an orthogonal matrix $P^TP=I$

Suppose $G$ meets the criteria of the problem then we can diagonalize $G=VDV^{-1}$ where $D$ is the same diagonal matrix as in the spectral theorem and $V$ is a matrix whose columns consist of a eigenvectors of $A$ that form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and have coordinates in $\{-1,1\}$ and includes the all ones eigenvector. The matrix $V$ is almost certainly not an orthogonal matrix unless there's some incredibly lucky graph.

Given a fixed basis of eigenvectors hence a fixed invertible matrix $V$ the only way we can have a non-isomorphic graph with the same eigenvectors is by having different eigenvalues corresponding to each vector. In particular the eigenvalue corresponding to the 1's eigenvector will be the regularity degree $d$ of the graph.

So given a graph $G$ with adjacency matrix $A=VDV^{-1}$ where the columns of $V$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ of eigenvectors of $A$ whose coordinates are in $\{-1,1\}$ and first column is all 1's, i propose constructing other examples by changing the diagonal matrix $D$ until $VDV^{-1}$ is a matrix with coordinates in $\{0,1\}$ and zeros on the diagonal. I haven't found a method better than guessing and checking but I've produced a couple of examples this way. Here is one:

Take $G$ to be the cube graph. [image: cube graph]
This graph has adjacency matrix 
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=VDV^{-1}$$
for 
$
V=\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$, and
$
D=\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}\right]
$

Setting

$D'=\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]$

gives

$VD'V^{-1}=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]$

Which has a corresponding $4$-regular graph that $G'$ that can't be isomorphic because the cube graph is $3$-regular. Here's a plot of said graph[image: 4-regular graph]

I've successfully done this strategy on the 4-dimensional cube graph as well. But admittedly, I don't have any better ideas for a more general method.

**Edit:** I've improved my method slightly, but it won't scale well. Instead of guessing and checking I manually entered 5 as the degree of regularity and considered the matrix as a multivariate polynomial of the other eigenvalues. The condition of the diagonals have to be 0 and the other entries are in $\{0,1\}$ can be turned into a multivariable polynomial system of equations that I used Gröbner basis to solve. Up to isomorphism there is exactly one $5$-regular graph:

[image: 5-regular on 8 vertices]

$
A=\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$
and
$
D=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3
\end{array}\right]
$

The GB approach also found a 2nd non-isomorphic 4-regular graph:
[image: 2nd 4-regular graph]
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2
\end{array}\right)
$$